# Google Play Console says app has been published but the app cannot be found on the PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

My Google Play Console says that my app has been published. I found it out on yesterday. But I cannot find my app anywhere on Google play store. This is the screenshot.

[image]

And the screenshot of App Releases:

[image]

Now when I click on the VIEW ON GOOGLE PLAY button I get this error message:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It takes usually 24 hours or sometimes 2 days to display in play store.

Currently app is in review process.

Comment: So why does it say Published?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait several hours to see your app available on the store after publication.

Comment: It's been almost four days and the app still hasn't been indexed on play store. Whenever I click on the VIEW ON GOOGLE PLAY button it still shows that the requested URL was not found. It's so so frustrating. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some times to be in play store search.